# Why can't I iterate over the same `vec.iter()` multiple times?

Tags: rust

I have a simple program as follows:

```
let x = vec![1,2,3];
let iterator = x.iter();
for z in iterator {}
for z in iterator {}
```

As we know, `x.iter()` is a reference to the value in `x`, but why cannot I iterate the iterator multiple times? It gives the following error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=994b0d342bc352c88fd3c1179fc9896f)):

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `iterator`
   --> src/main.rs:5:14
    |
3   |     let iterator = x.iter();
    |         -------- move occurs because `iterator` has type `std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
4   |     for z in iterator {}
    |              -------- `iterator` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
5   |     for z in iterator {}
    |              ^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `iterator`
```

The problem also exists with `(&x).into_iter()`, I cannot iterate it multiple times.

Comment: Because the iterator is moved?

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are stateful. An iterator is physically changing itself to loop through the data as it goes. At the end of the first `for` loop, even if you had ownership over it (which you don't since the `for` loop took ownership away from you), it would be a useless iterator pointing at the end of the list (one-past-the-end, in C++ terminology) and having no access to the actual data. The *point* of an iterator is that it statefully walks over the data structure, so to use it you have to consume it.

This is true not just in Rust but in most languages that have a concept of iterators. An "iterable" or "enumerable" data structure (like a list or array) is often iterable multiple times, but an "iterator" as a concept is the thing that does the work of iterating, and it only works once. This allows Rust (and other languages) to have lazy iterators implementing things like `.map` and `.filter` and also to iterate over infinite data structures.

Comment: Just a note: `Iterator` is implemented for `&mut Iterator`, so you can do that by `&mut iterator` (or `iterator.by_ref()`). Obviously this will be empty the second time unless you `break`ed (broke?) out of the first loop.

Comment: I am confused about the following question:
if x.iter() is a reference to the value in x, why the value is consumed in the first iterator

Comment: Thanks, I just got it, x is a iterable data structure while x.iter() is a iterator, so x can use reference to iterate multiple times, and x.iter()can only work once.
In addition, while iterating the x.iter(), it is a shared reference and can not mutate  the reference data

Comment: @blusekingZhuo You can run `x.iter()` multiple times to get multiple iterators. Yes, `.iter()` returns an iterator to immutable references, if you want to mutate, you need to use `.iter_mut()`.