# Iterable, .iter(&mut self) and mutable borrow from immutable data

Tags: rust, iterator

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = &vec![1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,47];
    let mut i = x.iter().map(|x|{2*x});

    while let Some(value) = i.next() {
        println!("{}", value);
    }
}
```

Why does this work?

If I change `let mut i =` into `let i =`, I get the error:

```
  |
3 |     let i = x.iter().map(|x|{2*x});
  |         - help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut i`
4 | 
5 |     while let Some(value) = i.next() {
  |                             ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Questions:

1. Do I really need to borrow as mutable? *(Maybe I am missing something here.)*
2. Why do I need to borrow as mutable?
3. What is really being mutable here? Is it `i` (the iterable) or `value` (its values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iterator in Rust is stateful. `.next` mutates it in-place to get the next value. Even if the underlying data structure is immutable, the iterator is basically a glorified pointer and is mutable. An immutable iterator is nigh useless: since it can't move across the data structure, it would always be accessing the same element.

Note that you don't need a mutable iterator if you're just passing ownership into something else. So the initial `x.iter()` doesn't need to explicitly be stored in a mutable location, since its ownership is immediately being passed onto `.map`. The `.map` iterator, on the other hand, is mutated by your function, so it needs to be stored in a variable marked as mutable.

> 1. Do I really need to borrow as mutable? *(Maybe I am missing something here.)*

Yes, your code is correct. Though `for value in i` would be more idiomatic.

> 2. Why do I need to borrow as mutable?

Since the iterator is moving (statefully) over the data, it needs to be able to change its own local state to change which element it's pointing to.

> 3. What is really being mutable here? Is it `i` (the iterable) or `value` (its values)?

The *iterator* `i` is mutable. The iterable is `x` and it is not iterable in your example.

See also [my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72539381/2288659), which explains the same concept.

Comment: Actually `for value in i` doesn't require `i` to be mutable since it is moved into the loop ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=32ede91f7941df3d7b1f8b02a0d9ab1f)).

Answer (score 2):

The iterator `i` must be mutable because it has internal state that updates when `next` is called. That's how the `Iterator` trait works.

You can see that `Iterator::next` mutably borrows `self`.

```
trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```